# Closure of an open set given by a union

Tags: general-topology

Consider the real numbers with the usual topology and set, $A=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left( n - \frac{1}{2n}, n+\frac{1}{2n}\right) $

$A$ is open in $\mathbb{R} $ since is the union of open intervals. **I wonder if it is also closed**. If it is not, then what is its closure?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not closed. $3/2$ belongs to $\bar A$ but not to $A$.

In fact $\bar A=A\cup\{n-\frac1{2n},n+\frac1{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\}=\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left[n - \frac{1}{2n}, n+\frac{1}{2n}\right]$.

You are basically adding the end points of each interval to get $\bar A$.

The intervals in the union are disjoint. For any point $x$ not in the union, you can always find an open interval $U$ containing $x$ such that $U\cap A=\phi$. For every point in $\{n-\frac1{2n},n+\frac1{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$, every open interval containing the said point intersects with $A$.

Comment: Thanks Johri. That was my first thought. So here is an example of *the closure of the union is the union of the closures* which it is true in general. I think that idea made me get stuck here.

Comment: Closure of the union is a **superset** of the union of the closures. However, the closure of union of finitely many sets is equal to the union of their closures. Take for example, $A_n=[1/n,1],n\in\Bbb N$. Then $\text{cl}(A_n)=A_n,\cup\text{cl}(A_n)=\cup A_n=(0,1]$ but $\text{cl}(\cup A_n)=\text{cl}(0,1]=[0,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say 'it is not true in general' in the other comment. Thanks for the example! It was easy to understand for me now.

Comment: Since you know that closure of the union is a superset of the union of the closures, it is a good idea to take the union of the closures as the starting point to determine the closure of the union. Then you can consider points not in the union of the closures and determine whether they lie in the closure of the union, as I have done.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is clearly not closed, since its closure must contain $\frac12$, which is not in $A$. $A$ is, however, open: it is the union of smaller and smaller open intervals centred at the positive integers,

$$A=\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)\cup\left(\frac74,\frac94\right)\cup\left(\frac{17}6,\frac{19}6\right)\cup\ldots\;.$$

We know that the closure of $A$ must at the very least contain the closures of these intervals, so at the very least it includes the set

$$F=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}\left[n-\frac1{2n},n+\frac1{2n}\right]=\left[\frac12,\frac32\right]\cup\left[\frac74,\frac94\right]\cup\ldots\;.\tag{1}$$

Finally, it’s not hard to see that $\Bbb R\setminus F$ is open: it’s the union of the open ray $\left(\leftarrow,\frac12\right)$ and the open intervals between the closed intervals in $(1)$. Thus, $F$ is closed and must therefore be the closure of $A$.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Let me get this right. First you show that $F\supset \overline{A} $. Then you show that $F$ is closed. So this means that F is the smallest closed set containing A, hence it is its closure. Am I right?

Comment: @Senna: Not quite, though the error may just be a typo: I first showed that $A\subseteq F\color{red}{\subseteq}\operatorname{cl}A$ and then showed that $F$ is closed, making it the smallest closed containing $A$.